# Combining values of 3 different MySQL table, join table 1 and table 2 and check if table 3 values exist in this join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 MySQL tables to retrieve data of them.

table1 contains the rows:

```
id | name       | total_amount | product_id | date
---------------------------------------------
1  | some name  | some amount  | some pid   | some date
2  | some name1 | some amount1 | some pid1  | some date1
3  | some name2 | some amount2 | some pid2  | some date2
4  | some name3 | some amount3 | some pid3  | some date3
```

and table2:

```
product_id | product_name
-------------------
some pid   | some product name
some pid1  | some product name1
some pid2  | some product name2
some pid3  | some product name3
```

and table3:

```
id | total_amount  | product_id
-------------------------------
1  | some amount   | some pid 
2  | some amount2  | some pid2
```

I am using inner join between table1 and table 2 with their product_id to list values as following:

```
name       | total_amount | product_id | product_name        | date
--------------------------------------------------
some name  | some amount  | some pid   | some product name   | some date
some name1 | some amount1 | some pid1  | some product name1  | some date1
some name2 | some amount2 | some pid2  | some product name2  | some date2
some name3 | some amount3 | some pid3  | some product name3  | some date3
```

But, I dont want to show rows in join table list if total_amount and product_id of table3 has same values with total_amount and product_id of table1.

So I want my output be like:

```
name       | total_amount | product_id | product_name        | date
--------------------------------------------------
some name1 | some amount1 | some pid1  | some product name1  | some date1
some name3 | some amount3 | some pid3  | some product name3  | some date3
```

Is it possible to do this with SQL Query or should I try to do it with my client side language PHP?

Comment: where is `Join Query` ? should be table3 join colum IS NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yu can use the following query:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id 
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t3.product_id = t2.product_id AND t1.total_amount = t3.total_amount
WHERE t3.product_id IS NULL
```

The above query joins `table1` and `table2` on field `product_id` and filters out records in case there is a matching record in `table3` having the same `product_id` and `total_amount` values.

Answer (score 1):

The straight-forward way is to use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` :

```
select t1.name, t1.total_amount, t1.product_id, t2.product_name, t1.date
from t1
join t2 on t2.product_id = t1.product_id
where (t1.total_amount, t1.product_id) not in
(
  select t3.total_amount, t3.product_id
  from t3
);
```